# Spark SQL sort string in each row

Tags: sql, apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
+-------+
|letters|
+-------+
|  [b,a]|
|[f,c,s]|
|[m,d,l]|
+-------+
```

I am trying to sort the letters in alphabetic order for each row. The final result should be:

```
+-------+
|letters|
+-------+
|  [a,b]|
|[c,f,s]|
|[d,m,l]|
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `letters` is an array column, you can sort it directly:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sort_array

df2 = df.withColumn("sortedCol", sort_array('letters', False))
```

Answer (score 0):

If Someone is using the Microsoft.Spark.Sql Assembly you can do that using SortArray Function.

This is specific to someone using spark from .Net.

You can find the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.functions.sortarray?view=spark-dotnet